# Grid of images with captions as column name

Tags: floats, subcaption

I am new to latex. I want to create exactly similar grid as shown in image below except I want 'ground truth', 'baseline' and 'proposed' text on top. Can I refer single images from grid elsewhere? I am using overleaf environment.

[image]

Comment: welcome to tex.se! what you try so far? can you show this in form of small but complete document (minimal working example)?

Comment: sorry that I did not have any clue about grouping and I am using template provided by university so MWE would be difficult.

Comment: well, than it may happens, that answers will not fit to your document ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are quite a few ways you could accomplish this.  You could use a `tabular` environment.  But the first approach I'll show you is using TikZ

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[picture format/.style={inner sep=2pt,}]

  \node[picture format]                   (A1)               {\includegraphics[width=1in]{images/oak_tree}};
  \node[picture format,anchor=north]      (B1) at (A1.south) {\includegraphics[width=1in]{images/restaurant}};

  \node[picture format,anchor=north west] (A2) at (A1.north east) {\includegraphics[width=1in]{images/oak_tree}};
  \node[picture format,anchor=north]      (B2) at (A2.south)      {\includegraphics[width=1in]{images/restaurant}};

  \node[picture format,anchor=north west] (A3) at (A2.north east) {\includegraphics[width=1in]{images/oak_tree}};
  \node[picture format,anchor=north]      (B3) at (A3.south)      {\includegraphics[width=1in]{images/restaurant}};

  %% Captions

  \node[anchor=south] (C1) at (A1.north) {\bfseries Ground Truth};
  \node[anchor=south] (C2) at (A2.north) {\bfseries Baseline};
  \node[anchor=south] (C3) at (A3.north) {\bfseries Proposed};

\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Comparisons of our proposed architecture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

If you're not familiar with TikZ, it's worth acquainting yourself with it.  You can do some very cool things with it.  However, there can be a steep learning curve.  Details of the syntax will be explained below.

As I mentioned above, you can use a `tabular` environment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\setlength\tabcolsep{2pt}%%
\centering
\begin{tabular}{ccc}
 \textbf{Ground Truth} &
 \textbf{Baseline} &
 \textbf{Proposed} \\
 \includegraphics[width=1in]{images/oak_tree} &
 \includegraphics[width=1in]{images/oak_tree} &
 \includegraphics[width=1in]{images/oak_tree} \\
 \includegraphics[width=1in]{images/restaurant} &
 \includegraphics[width=1in]{images/restaurant} &
 \includegraphics[width=1in]{images/restaurant} 
\end{tabular}
\caption{Comparisons of our proposed architecture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

And this will essentially create an image much like the image posted above.

**Discussion**

The advantage of the `tabular` approach is that it's very straight-forward.  If you're unfamiliar with the `array` package, I recommend checking it out.  It adds additional features to `tabular` and `array` environments and makes them easier to modify to your liking.

The advantage of the TikZ approach is that you have a lot finer control over the presentation of the *figure*.  I would not recommend TikZ as a substitute for `tabular`, but depending on what you intend to do with such a format, you might like TikZ.

Though to the uninitiated the TikZ syntax may look complex, it's actually fairly simple.  I use the `node` syntax which has the following components:

```
\node[<options>] (<node name>) at (<location>) {<content>};
```

Where `(<node name>)` and `at (<location>)` are optional.

Nodes can be placed relative to each other, which is what I've done.

The `picture format/.style={....}` is a way of passing formatting options that will be reused for each node.  All this *style* is accomplishing here is determining the amount of white space around each image:  `inner sep=2pt`.

The *anchors* are the real beauty here for placing nodes relative to each other.  For each node created, there are a variety of useful child nodes created--each named according to the parent node name.  For a parent node named `A1`,   the child nodes will be  `A1.south`, `A1.south east`, `A1.east`, `A1.north east`, etc.  There are quite a few other child nodes that are created, not just those named according to cardinal directions: for example, `A1.baseline` and a few others.  These child nodes facilitate *anchoring* each node relative to one another.

I strongly recommend reading the TikZ manual on nodes.  The introductory material isn't too hard to assimilate.

Comment: Oh thank you, I do know tabular so I think I would stick with it for a while.

Answer (score 1):

with use of `subfigures` from package `subcaption` the code is short and simple:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[skip=1ex,labelfont=bf, textfont=it]{caption}
\usepackage[textfont=rm]{subcaption}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[!ht]
    \centering
    \setkeys{Gin}{width=\linewidth}
\begin{subfigure}{0.3\textwidth}
    \caption*{Ground truth}
\includegraphics{example-image-a}\\[3pt]
\includegraphics{example-image-b}
\end{subfigure}
\hfil
\begin{subfigure}{0.3\linewidth}
    \caption*{Baseline}
\includegraphics{example-image-a}\\[3pt]
\includegraphics{example-image-b}
\end{subfigure}
\hfil
\begin{subfigure}{0.3\linewidth}
    \caption*{Proposed}
\includegraphics{example-image-a}\\[3pt]
\includegraphics{example-image-b}
\end{subfigure}
    \caption{Comparison of our proposed architecture with \dots}
    \label{fig:comparison}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The OP wants the captions on top.  Can you do that with subfigure?  I don't know.  I would love to see how.

Comment: @A.Ellett, thanks for comment. i overlooked this. now is corrected.